# Rails Tutorial Chapter 9: Authorization Redirect tests failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I have looked through pretty much every Rails Tutorial Chapter 9 question on StackOverflow. No one seems to be having this same issue. Maybe it's just a typo or something stupid I've missed and I just need some fresh eyes. Any help would be appreciated.

Errors:

```
Failures:

1) Authentication authorization as non-admin user submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action
 Failure/Error: specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/signin>.
   Expected "http://www.example.com/" to be === "http://www.example.com/signin".
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:60:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action
 Failure/Error: specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/signin>.
   Expected "http://www.example.com/" to be === "http://www.example.com/signin".
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:108:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action
 Failure/Error: specify { response.should redirect_to(root_url) }
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/signin>.
   Expected "http://www.example.com/" to be === "http://www.example.com/signin".
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:113:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:60 # Authentication authorization as non-admin user submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:108 # Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:113 # Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action
```

Authentication spec:

```
 require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign in') }
    it { should have_title('Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Sign in" }

        it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        it { should have_error_message('Invalid') }

        describe "after visiting another page" do
            before { click_link "Home" }
            it { should_not have_error_message('Invalid') }
        end

    end # End of invalid Sign in Tests

    describe "with valid information" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before { valid_signin(user) }

        it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Users',       href: users_path) }
        it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
        it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
        it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end

    end # End of valid Sign in Tests

  end # End of Sign in Tests

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "as non-admin user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:non_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      before { sign_in non_admin, no_capybara: true }

      describe "submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action" do
        before { delete user_path(user) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end # End of DELETE request
    end # End of Authentication->authorization->as non-admin

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end # End of Authen->author->nonsignedin->User controller->visiting edit

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { patch user_path(user) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end # End of submitting update

        describe "visiting the user index" do
          before { visit users_path }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end # End of Auth-autho->not signed in->user index
      end # End of Authen->author->nonsignedin->Users controller
      describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
        before do
          visit edit_user_path(user)
          fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        describe "after signing in" do
          it "should render the desired protected page" do
            expect(page).to have_title('Edit user')
          end
        end
      end
    end # End of Authentication->authorization->for non-signed-in users

    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

      describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action" do
        before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user')) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
        before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_url) }
      end
    end
  end # End of Authentication->authorization

end # End of Authentication Tests
```

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :signed_in_user,     only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user,       only: [:edit, :update]
before_action :admin_user,         only: :destroy
before_action :signed_in_redirect, only: [:new, :create]

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted."
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation, :admin)
    end

    # Before filters

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

    def signed_in_redirect
      redirect_to root_url, note: "Already signed in" if signed_in?
    end

end
```

Let me know if there's anything additional I should post in order to help you help me. Thanks in advance.

-EDIT-

Sessions helper:

```
    module SessionsHelper

    def sign_in(user)
        remember_token = User.new_remember_token
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
        user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
        self.current_user = user
    end

    def signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    def current_user=(user)
        @current_user = user
    end

    def current_user
        remember_token = User.hash(cookies[:remember_token])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
    end

    def current_user?(user)
        user == current_user
    end

    def sign_out
        current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token,
                                      User.hash(User.new_remember_token))
        cookies.delete(:remember_token)
        self.current_user = nil
    end

    def redirect_back_or(default)
        redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
        session.delete(:return_to)
    end

    def store_location
        session[:return_to] = request.url if request.get?
    end


end
```

-EDIT 2-

utilities.rb:

```
include ApplicationHelper

    def sign_in(user, options={})
      if options[:no_capybara]
        # Sign in when not using Capybara.
        remember_token = User.new_remember_token
        cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
        user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
      else
        visit signin_path
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end
    end

    def valid_signin(user)
      fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
      fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      click_button "Sign in"
    end

    RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
      match do |page|
        expect(page).to have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: message)
      end


end
```

-EDIT 3-

edited portion of `spec/support/utilities.rb`

```
    def sign_in(user, options={})
      if options[:no_capybara]
        # Sign in when not using Capybara.
        remember_token = User.new_remember_token
        cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
        user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
        puts user
      else
        visit signin_path
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end
    end
```

Edited portion of `app/controllers/users_controller`

```
def signed_in_user
  puts current_user
  unless signed_in?
    store_location
    redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
  end
end
```

Output from `rspec spec/`

```
╭─von at Vons-Mac in ~/dev/web/rails/sample_app on updating-users✘✘✘ using ‹ruby-2.1.0@railstutorial_4_0› 14-05-15 - 19:33:59
╰─○ rspec spec/
..
F
F
F
.
#<User:0x00000106b79240>
.
.
.
...................................................#<User:0x000001026f1370>
.#<User:0x00000106361850>
.#<User:0x00000106d7b688>
.#<User:0x0000010267df38>
#<User:0x00000106a77220>
.#<User:0x00000107abc9f0>
#<User:0x0000010607c748>
.#<User:0x0000010686cd68>
#<User:0x00000101610ec0>
#<User:0x000001036d47b0>
#<User:0x00000101e54730>
.#<User:0x00000107bdc858>
.#<User:0x0000010244a590>
.........#<User:0x00000106b81008>
.#<User:0x00000106331a60>
.#<User:0x0000010629b330>
.#<User:0x0000010a96cae8>
#<User:0x0000010a092b48>
.#<User:0x0000010a9f8160>
#<User:0x0000010a09b1f8>
.#<User:0x0000010a0f84e8>
#<User:0x0000010aa6f580>
.#<User:0x000001064eef88>
#<User:0x0000010ab82080>
.#<User:0x00000106535320>
#<User:0x000001065c83c8>
.#<User:0x0000010665a1d8>
#<User:0x0000010a17d300>
.
```

And then the same errors before that basically said the user wasn't signed in when they should've been.

Comment: The common factor seems to be your `sign_in` method; I guess this is not working which is why these actions are going to the sign in page instead of root.  i.e. the user is not actually signed in before they do the action you are testing.  Can you share it?

Comment: Alright. Added sessions_helper, which contains the `sign_in` method.

Comment: Do you have `sign_in` method defined somewhere in `specs/spec_helper.rb` or `specs/support/`? If so, can you provide the code please?

Comment: Absolutely. I've added another edit to include the contents from spec/support/utilities.rb

Comment: Thanks for the two updates; I suggest you do some debugging in the `signed_in?` and `current_user` methods of your sessions helper and the `sign_in` method of utilties.  From the errors I think you will find `signed_in?` returns false because `current_user` is not able to find the user from the cookie, possbily because `sign_in` is not generating and storing the cookie correctly.

Comment: Ok. I'm not really sure how to debug. I did some reading, but am still confused and have no clue where to begin. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: There are many different ways but for quick simplicity you can just stick in `puts` statements and you will see it output when you run the test.  For example, I am suspicious about whether the cookie is being set so putting `puts remember_token` in the `current_user` method of your sessions helper will output the value it has at this time.  It's a quick hack to help you narrow down where the problem originates.  There's more about different methods of debugging in the Rails guide - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: Where should I see output? I run `rspec spec/` in my terminal and only see the errors. I check the windows running the `spork` and `rails s` commands as well and... nothing. I ran `rake db:test:prepare`. Then re-ran `spork` and `rails s` in their respective windows. Still nothing. Ideas? @GraemeMcLean

Comment: For a `puts` you should see the output where you run `rspec` from.  Maybe try something at the top of the `sign_in` method in `utilities.rb` or even in `signed_in_user` in the users controller.  Once you can see something being output from your trace statements then you can move them to try and follow the flow through the methods and so work out where it is failing.

Comment: Ok. I added some more `puts` so I'll post the updated bits where I put them (no pun). And I got some output which I'll add to the original post because it seems... cryptic to me, if nothing else. And I appreciate the continued help. I've been pulling my hair out thinking I typed something wrong and poring over every character of the relevant files for at least 2 weeks. So... Thanks a lot. Really.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean do you have any ideas about what this output means? Thanks in advance. Anyone else is more than welcome to answer as well.

Comment: Have given up on this. If anyone finds a solution, please feel free to tell me about it.

Comment: +1, I am also doing the tutorial now and I am experiencing exactly the same problem

Comment: Maybe if enough people see this/report having the same issue, we can get in contact with Hartl about it. Hell I feel like the fact that it's not just me is 'enough people' quite honestly. @hp4k

Comment: To make it more mysterious, I am not sure if it is just me but the app works absolutely fine in the development environment when I run it in the browser, i.e. it redirects me to the root_url. It is just the tests that are a problem.

Comment: Exactly. That's the EXACT problem I'm having as well. Does it work in production? Ie did you deploy to Heroku and test that env? Full disclosure: I didn't personally. Just something I thought about.

Comment: @keaglin It turns out I must have had a very inconspicuous typo somewhere in the sign_in function in utilities.rb as copy-pasting the code from the tutorial helped!

Comment: I'll try that then. Can you give me the page or section or figure number of the code bit you used?

Comment: @keaglin Sure, it was Listing 9.6.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take another look at it. Happy trails.

Comment: Wondering if you did the chapter 8 exercises. @hp4k. Because I can't copy/paste and have it be completely right. I use 'User.hash' instead of 'User.digest'. Starting to think not as many people do the exercises and maybe that's where my problem lies. Because the Railscast he links to in order to complete the exercise is from 3.2 anyway. I think I may just start over one last time and skip all exercises. Just get through the tutorial and then maybe come back once my understanding of Rails is much better and try to see what I did wrong. Thanks anyway to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is helpful 5 years later. But I realized like a year or 2 ago that the issue was this: I was returning the entire User record when I should've been returning a field. Thus, the failing test and resulting error.